# Function declared on injected file not recognize from background.js in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, virtual-reality, webvr

I'm trying to use https://github.com/povdocs/webvr-starter-kit to create a chrome PageAction extension.

On my `manifest.json` file, I've used `content_scripts` to load `jquery.js` and another `inject.js`.

On my `inject.js`, I've the following codes:

```
function initVR() {
    VR.floor();
    VR.box({ color: '#FFFFFF' }).moveTo(0, 1.4, 0).setScale(5,4,0);
    var text = VR.text({
        wrap: 4.1,
        font: '24pt Roboto',
        textAlign: 'left',
        fillStyle : '#000000',
        text : 'Hello world test'
    })
    .moveTo(.1, 1.4, 0);
}
```

on my `background.js` file, I've

```
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
    file:  "src/inject/vr.dev.js"
  }, function(){
    initVR();    //Calling the function I declared on inject.js
});
```

The idea here is, when a person clicks on the pageAction button, it injects the `vr.dev.js` and initialize the setup.

When I implement this, I get an error saying `initVR()` is not defined. What am I doing incorrect?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use message passing to communicate to content script,because the extension of your browser is a single background script,it have to identify the tab

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

Answer (score 3):

Your background script does not have access to your content script. You should instead send a message from background.js to your page and have a listener there to call the function `initVR()`